# Android Jetpack compose IconButton padding

Tags: android, android-button, android-jetpack-compose

How to remove padding in an IconButton ? I want items in my column have the same start padding

[image: preview image]

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth() 
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
) {
    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
        Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Search)
    }
    Text("Some text")
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The space is due to **accessibility** touch targets and a default size of `48.dp`.

Starting with `1.2.0` the best best way to change the default behaviour and remove the extra space is disabling the `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement` and applying a `size` modifier:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
        onClick = { }
    ) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Search,
            "contentDescription",
        )
    }
}
```

Pay attention because in this way it is possible that if the component is placed near the edge of a layout / near to another component without any padding, there will not be enough space for an accessible touch target.

---

With `1.0.0` the **`IconButton`** applies a default size with the internal modifier: **`IconButtonSizeModifier = Modifier.size(48.dp)`**.

You can modify it using something like:

```
IconButton(modifier = Modifier.
        then(Modifier.size(24.dp)),
    onClick = { }) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Search,
        "contentDescription",
        tint = Color.White)
}
```

It is important the use of [**`.then`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#then) to apply the **`size`** in the right sequence.

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted the touch target width and height to wrap content?  I tried Modifier.then(Modifier.wrapContentSize() but that did not work

Comment: Hi, could you verify `then` is still needed? According to [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/991dd861adc22eb7a528561554a3ca5a4cd9879c/compose/ui/ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier.kt#L208) `Modifier.then(x)` is equal to `x`. Also it seems to be working the same without `this`, am I missing something?

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thanks for the feedback, very appreciated. I've updated the answer. [Previously](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/commit/bed1b7549d6bbd2e4b55182427ec5d2a8f88f3ed#diff-8b55aeb43f3cbd36d9bca7bcc124cdcc1b0786917a986803e8e6f8b120727f8fL76) the `IconButton` was hardcoded to be `48.dp` in size with a `then` modifier, here the reason to use the `then` modifier with `1.0.0`. Now the best solution is different.

Answer (score 10):

Wrap the `IconButton` with `CompositionLocalProvider` to override the value of `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement` which enforces a minimum touch target of `48.dp`.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false,
) {
    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
            contentDescription = "Search",
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `IconButton` just for handling click listener, instead of:

```
IconButton(onClick = { // Todo -> handle click }) {
    Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Search)
}
```

You can use:

```
Icon(
    asset = Icons.Filled.Search,
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { // Todo -> handle click },
)
```

With this way you don't need to remove extra paddings.

Comment: Good option, but you don't get the click ripple in this case

Comment: @gtxtreme you can actually, there is two ways: either change default behavior of `LocalIndication` to `rememberRipple()` or pass `indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true)` inside your `clickable` modifier